# number reversal program gives only the first digit in output instead of the whole number

Tags: java

```
String s1;
int a, b, c = 0;
s1 = t1.getText();
a = Integer.parseInt(s1);
while (a > 0) {
    b = a % 10;
    c = c * 0 + b;
    a = a / 10;
}
t2.setText("" + c);
```

here t1,t2 are text fields. Please let me know where did i go wrong because i am just getting the first digit of the number which I enter in the output and not the whole number.

Comment: And this is a program to reverse a String or I've just missed something?

Comment: @ThrashBean Actually, to reverse the digits in a number.

Comment: It reverts the decimal representation of an integer (initially coming from a string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your incrementation of `c` is `c = c * 0 + b;` You probably want to multiply by `10` instead of `0`: `c = c * 10 + b;`

Comment: You are trying to shift the currently accumulated number (c) by one digit and add another digit at the end. Shifting by a digit in decimal notation is multiplying by 10. Multiplying by 0 deletes all your previous digits at every iteration.